# Merge multiple files with join

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

Is there some workaround to join multiple files at once based on the first column? Usually, I would do:
 `join File1 File2 > File1+File2` and `File1+File2 File3 > final_output`

Example files:

File1:

```
1 test1
2 test3
3 test4
4 test5
7 test7
```

File2:

```
1 example1
2 example2
3 example3
4 example4
8 example8
```

File3:

```
1 foo1
2 foo2
3 foo3
4 foo4
10 foo10
```

Considering that f.e. fifth line may differs in each file, and there is `n` number of files. 
**Edit:**

Example output:

```
1 test1 example1 foo1
2 test2 example2 foo2
3 test3 example3 foo3
4 test4 example4 foo4
```

On the other hand, I am not sure how lines that don't match in column1 will be processed (fifth line)
Thanks

Comment: can you post the expected result?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question.

Comment: _"I am not sure how lines that don't match in column1 will be processed"_  How do you want them to be processed.  In the example, they are removed.  Is that the goal?

Comment: @John1024 they can be removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically like this for your 3 files example

```
$ join file2 file3| join file1 -
1 test1 example1 foo1
2 test3 example2 foo2
3 test4 example3 foo3
4 test5 example4 foo4
```

**But important** all your input files must be sorted already (`sort -k 1b,1`, numerical sorted like your example may not work!). So the example above sorted on-the-fly could be written in `bash` like this:

```
join <(sort -k 1b,1 file2) <(sort -k 1b,1 file3) | join <(sort -k 1b,1 file1) -\
  | sort -k 1n,1
```

And finally the generic case for n files using a recursive function (tested in `bash`).:

```
xjoin() {
    local f
    local srt="sort -k 1b,1"

    if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
            echo "xjoin: need at least 2 files" >&2
            return 1
    elif [ "$#" -lt 3 ]; then
            join <($srt "$1") <($srt "$2")
    else
            f=$1
            shift
            join <($srt "$f") <(xjoin "$@")
    fi
}

xjoin file1 file2 file3 | sort -k 1n,1
```

If you know what you are doing you may omit the sort pipes. But from my experience `join` without explicit `sort` is very often the cause of trouble.

Comment: *and there is **n** number of files*

Comment: @rudimeler can this be piped like: `join file1 file2 | join file3 - | join file4 - `  and so on? Will that work?

Comment: Yes, I thought either writing a loop to create such long pipe command *or* using a recursive shell function.

Comment: @fugitive I've added a recursive function just for the sports. ;)

Comment: Great answer, @rudimeier . The join prints only the matching rows. How to print nonmatching rows by padding 0.