# combining multiple files by the first column

Tags: awk, rhel

I have more than fifty files with a distinct name in a directory. For example:

File1:

```
Type,A,
RR,1,
CD,2,
```

File2:

```
Type,B,
CD,2,
FG,3,
```

File3:

```
Type,C,
RR,5,
FG,8,
QR,9,
```

Desired output

```
Type,A,B,C,
CD,2,2,,
FG,,3,8,
QR,,,9,
RR,1,,5
```

I tried with `join` and `paste` but no luck... Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple files with join](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364735/merge-multiple-files-with-join)

Comment: @Kusalananda I have tried that, but my scenario is bit different from that question. First, number of files will increase and file names are distinct. Secondly, `join` may give only common values.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate gives a generic function for joining any number of files. The `join` command is able to return all lines from both files with `-a 1 -a 2`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks,it works .... but with a little issue... with `-a 1 -a 2` gives me `QR,9,` instead of the desired output. `QR,,,9,`

Comment: Why are there all the trailing commas?

Comment: @glennjackman its just the csv out, we can ignore while writing to csv.

Comment: Because all the files don't have all the row prefixes, `join` will never know to add blanks for row prefixes that it hasn't seen before.   You either need to add all the prefixes to all the files, and leave the second field blank where there's no value, or you need to preprocess the files to acquire a list of all the prefixes, and then process each additional file to fill in the numbers where a prefix is in the file and has a number in the second field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some fairly tricky GNU awk. GNU awk (`gawk`) required for [arrays-of-arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html)

```
gawk -F, '
    NR  == 1 {n=1; header[n] = $1}
    FNR == 1 {n++; header[n] = $2; next}

    !($1 in data) {data[$1][1] = $1}
    {data[$1][n] = $2}

    # from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html
    function join(array, start, end, sep,    result, i)
    {
        if (sep == "")
            sep = " "
        else if (sep == SUBSEP) # magic value
            sep = ""
        result = array[start]
        for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
            result = result sep array[i]
        return result
    }

    END {
        print join(header, 1, n, FS)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"   # for sorted output
        for (type in data)
            print join(data[type], 1, n, FS)
    }
' file{1,2,3}
```

```
Type,A,B,C
CD,2,2,
FG,,3,8
QR,,,9
RR,1,,5
```

I'm assuming that each file has 2 columns, so it's not completely generic.

---

A version that does not rely on GNU awk (tested with mawk)

```
mawk -F, '
    NR  == 1 {n=1; header[n] = $1}
    FNR == 1 {n++; header[n] = $2; next}
    {key[$1]; data[$1,n] = $2}
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "%s%s", header[i], (i==n ? ORS : FS)
        for (type in key) {
            printf "%s%s", type, FS
            for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
                printf "%s%s", data[type,i], (i==n ? ORS : FS)
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}
```

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7.... getting syntax error `data[$1][1]`

Comment: According the the [NEWS file in git](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/NEWS?h=gawk-4.1.3), arrays-of-arrays were added in gawk 4.0: and according to the [NEWS check-in log in CVS](https://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gawk/gawk-stable/NEWS?view=log), 3.1.7 was released in 2009 --can you upgrade?

Comment: ok... i will check.

Answer (score 0):

This is not particularly hard to do even without real multi-dimensional arrays:

```
/Type/ { type=$2; types[$2] = 1 }
!/Type/ { data[type,$1] = $2; keys[$1] = 1 }
END {
    m = asorti(types)
    value = "Type"
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        value = value "," types[i];
    }
    print value;
    n = asorti(keys)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        value=keys[i]
        for (k = 1; k <= m; k++) {
            value = value "," data[types[k],keys[i]]
        }
        print value;
    }
}
```

However, you still need GNU `awk` for the sorting functions.