# Merging two CSVs based on matching first column (with header)

Tags: bash, python, csv, data

I have two CSV files. One of which contains a lot of data:

main.csv

```
Order No.,invoiceNumber,invoiceAmount,invoiceAmountNet
20001,20010,500,5
20002,20011,400,4
20003,20012,300,3
20004,20013,200,2
20005,20014,200,1
```

While my other CSV file has less information:

october-2020.csv

```
Order No.,Timestamp,ID
20001,2020-10-01 12:00:00,123456
20002,2020-10-02 13:00:00,123457
```

And my goal is to create a new CSV file based on october-2020.csv and adding information from main.csv. The common information is the Order No.:

output.csv

```
Order No.,invoiceNumber,invoiceAmount,invoiceAmountNet,Order No.,Timestamp,ID
20001,20010,500,5,20001,2020-10-01 12:00:00,123456
20002,20011,400,4,20002,2020-10-02 13:00:00,123457
```

How could this be scripted? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this -  Merge multiple files with join
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364735/85046 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `join` on the first field (`Order No.`) of both files with `,` as field separator:

```
join -t, -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3 main.csv october-2020.csv > output.csv
```

and

```
$ cat output.csv
Order No.,invoiceNumber,invoiceAmount,invoiceAmountNet,Order No.,Timestamp,ID
20001,20010,500,5,20001,2020-10-01 12:00:00,123456
20002,20011,400,4,20002,2020-10-02 13:00:00,123457
```

Since both files are already sorted on the first field, we don't need to sort them manually.
And since you want the `Order No.` to be present twice in the output, the fields are specified with the `-o` option (fields 1-4 of the first input file, fields 1-3 of the second file).

Answer (score 0):

```
csv-sqlite -i main.csv -i october-2020.csv \
   'select i1.invoiceNumber, i1.invoiceAmount, i1.invoiceAmountNet, i2.*
      from input1 i1, input2 i2
     where i1."Order No." = i2."Order No."' | csv-header --remove-types
```

csv-sqlite is from [csv-nix-tools](https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools)